# how to get cpu usage of prev. actions in contract call?

Tags: smart-contract

Is it possible to figure out *before transaction is completed*, how much CPU an action in a smart contract will use? E.G. I make transaction with X actions + call to my smart - contract. Is possible to know how much CPU prev. actions took?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do a very rough estimation based on previous action-calls by using the [Hyperion-History get_actions-endpoint](https://api.eossweden.org/v2/docs/static/index.html#/history/get_v2_history_get_actions). The data returned has

```
  "cpu_usage_us": ...
  "net_usage_words": ...
  "account_ram_deltas": ...
```

By using the data returned you could do estimates based on average values etc.but many other factors will play a role and cpu-usage is not 100% predictable.